# Question on how to donate to CiviCRM

Tags: support

Our non-profit has increased membership by over 30% this year, and our annual meeting event has over 100 signups. This has all been driven by CiviCRM, installed in January for the first time. I think I can get the board to approve a one-time donation to CiviCRM, with perhaps more to follow. I can't find a link on the CiviCRM project site to make a one time donation. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making a donation we are growing Civicrm. I am happy to help you.
You can find the link for donation by clicking **support us** from civicrm home page **https://civicrm.org/** website

In this page you can find a link for contribution saying **monthly contribution to support our work**.

If you want to contribute just for once then don’t select the option **(I want to contribute this amount every month)** in the payment form

Or you can use the following link 
https://civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=47

Or use the below link too

https://civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=63&src=download

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your organization can sign up as [CiviCRM Members](https://civicrm.org/membership). This is more than just a donation, as it also gives members-only benefits to help your organization use CiviCRM more effectively, such as discounts on CiviCons, staff trainings, video tutorials, and a growing collection of plugin services such as CiviMonitor.

Comment: Don't think we are interested in membership, but I finally found the monthly contribution link in the text of the support us page.

Comment: Looks like CiviCRM is a 'pay for bug fix' model now. So any 'donations' will go to paying for bug fixes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. 100% of donations to CiviCRM go into the project. This has always been the case. This funding is used for all project needs - development, infrastructure & hosting, security, project management, and yes bug fixes.

Comment: What I mean is that donations, at least in our case, should be targeted to specific bugs. Doesn't the Jira funding thingy allow for this?

Comment: I see. Yes you can fund specific issues via https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue